# null value in ListBody

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a method that returns a List of Widgets.

```
 List<Widget> _children(List<Suburb> suburbs){
      return
        suburbs.map((suburb){
          Text(suburb.name);
        }).toList()
      ;

  }
```

I'm using this method for the children in the show `showDialog()`method:

```
                       showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return SimpleDialog(
                            children: _children(suburbs), //But this works [Text(suburbs[0].name)]
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            title: Text('Pick your suburb'),
                          );
                        }),
```

But I'm getting the error
`ListBody's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0`But this works: `[Text(suburbs[0].name)]`
Any idea why this is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't return the **Text** in your map

Add a return just before the **Text**

Like this

```
 List<Widget> _children(List<Suburb> suburbs){
      return
        suburbs.map((suburb){
          return Text(suburb.name);
        }).toList()
      ;
  }
```

Or you can use the arrow function like this

```
 List<Widget> _children(List<Suburb> suburbs){
      return suburbs.map((suburb) => Text(suburb.name)).toList();
  }
```